# How to add a second annotation to an already annotated queryset with django models

Tags: python, django

I want to create a queryset with following columns

movie.id | movie.title | movie.description | movie.maximum_rating | movie.maximum_rating_user

Below are my models and the code I have tried.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
    
class Rating(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ratings")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ratings")
    score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=9)
    
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=4096)
```

When i run below code the following is printed in console:
(basically this shows all data in the experimental database)

**views.py**

```
def index(request, movie_id):
    movies = Movie.objects.all().annotate(
            maximum_rating=Max('ratings__score'), 
            maximum_rating_user=F('ratings__user')
            )
    for movie in movies:
        print(movie.id, movie.title, movie.description, movie.maximum_rating, movie.maximum_rating_user)
    return HttpResponse("")
```

| id | title | description | rating | user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jumping Cats | Running wild | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | Jumping Cats | Running wild | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | Jumping Cats | Running wild | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | Jumping Cats | Running wild | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | Terminator | I'll be back! | 8 | 1 |
| 2 | Terminator | I'll be back! | 6 | 2 |
| 2 | Terminator | I'll be back! | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | Terminator | I'll be back! | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | Dumbo | Walt Disney | 6 | 1 |
| 3 | Dumbo | Walt Disney | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | Dumbo | Walt Disney | 9 | 3 |
| 3 | Dumbo | Walt Disney | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | Thin Red Line | Wartimes | 9 | 1 |
| 4 | Thin Red Line | Wartimes | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | Thin Red Line | Wartimes | 5 | 3 |
| 4 | Thin Red Line | Wartimes | 8 | 4 |

Now i would like to modify the query so it only returns the row for each movie where the rating has the maximum value.

When i remove the second annotate the query returns a single row for each movie with the maximum rating but then the user is not annotated.

**views.py**

```
def index(request, movie_id):
    movies = Movie.objects.all().annotate(
            maximum_rating=Max('ratings__score'))
    for movie in movies:
        print(movie.id, movie.title, movie.description, movie.maximum_rating)
    return HttpResponse("")
```

| id | title | description | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jumping Cats | Running wild | 5 |
| 2 | Terminator | I'll be back! | 10 |
| 3 | Dumbo | Walt Disney | 9 |
| 4 | Thin Red Line | Wartimes | 9 |

How should i modify the query so it returns the abave queryset but annotes the user who posted the highest rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a [**`Subquery`** expression [Django-odc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to determine the user with the highest review:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

def index(request, movie_id):
    movies = Movie.objects.all().annotate(
        maximum_rating=Max('ratings__score'),
        max_user=Subquery(
            Rating.objects.filter(
                movie=OuterRef('pk')
            ).order_by('-score').values('user')[:1]
        )
    )
    for movie in movies:
        print(movie.id, movie.title, movie.description, movie.maximum_rating)
    return HttpResponse("")
```

Comment: Thank you Willem, works perfectly! For those django beginners, if you wonder how to make the value() method to return the actual usernamer, you have to use Django lookup notation like so: `values('user__username')`